# ¿Como hacer para que no me bote ningun resultado si la condicion no existe dentro de un with? Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una duda sobre esto, es posible haciendo uso del with y poniendo un where dentro de ella, que me muestan o no los datos?
Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
Cliente::(['pedido' => function ($query) {
  $query->where('id_pedido','999');
}])->get()
```

Donde es una relacion de `uno a muchos`(Un cliente puede hacer muchos pedidos). En mi tabla pedidos solo hay 3 registros:

```
[
  {
    'id_pedido':'1',
    'cliente_id': '1'
  },
  {
    'id_pedido':'2',
    'cliente_id': '2'
  },
  {
    'id_pedido':'3',
    'cliente_id': '3'
  }
]
```

Pero en la consulta que hize puse: `where('id_pedido','999')`. Esto me botara como resultado los clientes menos el pedido que hiz cono ese `id`, porque `no existe`.

Lo que que quiero saber es: ¿Como hacer para que no me bote ningun resultado si la condicion no existe?. En este caso del `Cliente-Pedido` con la condicio `where('id_pedido','999')`, no quiero que me arroje ningun resultado.

Esto lo pregunto porque estoy trabajando con estados y eso esta relacionado con muchas tablas asi que si utilizo una condicion que no existe igual me arrojara resultados que no quiero porque simplemente **la condicion no es valida**

Ojo: Las relaciones y los modelos ya estan bien efectuadas asi que seria innecesario ponerlas aca

Comment: Si entendí bien la pregunta, tendrías que consultar la existencia de la relación https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Gracias, leere la documentacion y si tengo dudas lo pondre. Hasta ahora utilizaba siempre el with y se complicaba mucho en hacer unas cosas @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar entonces whereHas;

```
Cliente::whereHas('pedido', function ($query) {
    $query->where('id_pedido', 999);
})->get();
```

referencia : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence