# Obtener columnas especificas usando whith() Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, livewire

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a la Base de Datos, usando Eloquent pero no consigo darle la forma adecuada....
Les explico: Tengo la tabla llamada Pacientes y una tabla llamada cirugias
Un paciente puede tener una o muchas cirugias.
Una cirugia pertenece a un solo paciente.
Tengo una tabla donde vacio toooodas las cirugias, pero tengo en la parte superior derecha un input donde quiero filtrar por el nombre de la paciente. Ya que cuando tengo 100 registros resulta dificil ubicar a uno en particular.

Yo tenia este codigo en mi livewire:

```
public function render()
{
   $cirugias = Cirugia::with('paciente')
  ->where('paciente.name', 'like', '%' . $this->TextBusqueda . '%')
  ->paginate(50);

   return view('livewire.clinic.cirugia.list-cirugias', [
       'cirugias' => $cirugias,
    ]);
}
```

Pero no me funciona....
No se si es posible consultar la lista de cirugias donde el nombre del paciente sea TextBusqueda. O tenga que hacerlo desde el modelo paciente
Ayuda Por Favor[![

> 

```
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                   
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Cedula</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Paciente</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Lugar</th>
                                    {{-- <th scope="col">Procedimientos</th> --}}
                                    <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($cirugias as $cirugia)
                                    <tr>
                                       
                                       
                                        <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
                                         <td>{{ $cirugia->paciente->cedula }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $cirugia->paciente->name }}</td> 
                                        <td>{{ $cirugia->fecha }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $cirugia->lugar }}</td> 
                                      
                                        {{-- Llama al metodod getStatusBadgeAttribute que esta en el modelo cita --}}
                                        {{-- <td>{{  strip_tags( $cirugia->note ) }}</td> --}}

                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{ route('clinic.cirugias.view', $cirugia) }}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-eye mr-2 text-gray"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="{{ route('clinic.cirugias.edit', $cirugia) }}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-edit mr-2"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href=""
                                                wire:click.prevent="confirmarEliminar( {{ $cirugia }} )">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzQw1.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzQw1.png)

Comment: En vez de traer todas las Cirugias pero sin el Paciente cuando no cumpla la condición, tendrías que consultar la existencia de la relación, para traer sólo las Cirugias que cumplan con la condición. Dale una mirada a esta [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406729/como-hacer-para-que-no-me-bote-ningun-resultado-si-la-condicion-no-existe-dentr/406797#406797) y a la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) de laravel

Answer (score 0):

No lo logre por eloquent, el que me pueda ayudar lo agradezco. Voy a usar una sentencia SQL equivalente.
SELECT cirugias.id, cirugias.paciente_id, pacientes.id,pacientes.cedula, pacientes.name from cirugias join pacientes WHERE ( (pacientes.id = cirugias.paciente_id) AND (pacientes.name LIKE ''%' . $TextBusqueda . '%''))